# Change node value with xml identity template

Tags: xslt

I have this xml and want to create an xml with every list_data changed to what is currently coming in xml batch_id for example XMTL-6021 in this case.  This is very simplified xml and transformation.  The xsl template contains many nodes that need to be changed to current batch_id.  I tried to use Identity template but the value of batch_id is not known in that template.
this is xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
    <Header>
        <Date>2021-07-28</Date>
        <Time>01:39:25</Time>
    </Header>
    <batch_id>XMTL-6021</batch_id>
</Message>
```

and this is xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" exclude-result-prefixes="#all"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/Message">
        <xsl:variable name="batchID" select="batch_id"/>
        <root>
        <worksheet_element>
            <plot type="BIEXPDOTPLOT-1">
                <list_data>NEW GATE VALD 2.Global Worksheets.Global Sheet1</list_data>
            </plot>
        </worksheet_element>
        <worksheet_element>
            <plot type="BIEXPDOTPLOT-2">
                <list_data>NEW GATE VALD 2.Global Worksheets.Global Sheet1</list_data>
            </plot>
        </worksheet_element>
        <worksheet_element>
            <plot type="BIEXPDOTPLOT-3">
                <list_data>NEW GATE VALD 2.Global Worksheets.Global Sheet1</list_data>
            </plot>
        </worksheet_element>
        <worksheet_element>
            <plot type="BIEXPDOTPLOT-4">
                <list_data>NEW GATE VALD 2.Global Worksheets.Global Sheet1</list_data>
            </plot>
        </worksheet_element>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the desire output should have

```
<list_data>XMTL-6021.Global Worksheets.Global Sheet1</list_data>
```

for all.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly (?), you only need to change:

```
            <list_data>NEW GATE VALD 2.Global Worksheets.Global Sheet1</list_data>
```

to:

```
            <list_data>
                <xsl:value-of select="$batchID"/>
                <xsl:text>.Global Worksheets.Global Sheet1</xsl:text>
            </list_data>
```

Comment: I do not want to do this in 100+ nodes manually.  I do not have control over the contents of template.  Is there a better way?  Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand your situation. If you want to modify many similar instructions in your stylesheet, you can use it as the input to another XSL transformation. But this would be a one-time process (I think?), so you could accomplish the same thing by a simple find/replace.

Comment: Template I provided is just a generic template, it suppose to dynamically change based on what is coming from an xml input file.  Request coming in the form of xml and the template should create another xml based on the input request.  I am doing this in ESB and I already created another template to change the contents.  I just thought there is another smarter way.

Comment: I still don't understand the process you describe. In each transformation, the XSLT stylesheet is a given, and the output is created by applying the stylesheet's instructions to the current input. If you want the instructions themselves to change based on the XML input, you will need to perform the transformation in two passes: first, generate the required stylesheet, then apply it to the input. However, I doubt very much you actually need such complex process. In most cases, a single stylesheet that accommodates a variety of inputs is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you Michael for taking time to look into this.  Someone showed me how to do this long time ago, I forgot, I am just looking where I implemented this.  If I find it I will posted here.  I wish I knew your email address!  Thanks again.